# addEventListener not working for ajax generated content (pure javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I loaded content with divs dynamically via ajax (pure javascript) inside "test". Now, when I click on a child div of index 6 I want an alertbox to appear but this is not the case.

How do I make the click event work? Gets is called if the ajax request has been completed. It works fine If I remove the eventlistener and just add an alertbox, displaying the appropiate content. With the the eventlistener it utterly fails to bind a handler onto the target div.

```
function gets(){
    document.getElementById("test").children[6].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(document.getElementById("test").children[6])
    })
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon on the end of `alert` and `})`.

Comment: @Cyval the code is valid....ok I didnt cache my elements but oh well

Comment: This looks like a delegation problem, follow the [link](http://codepen.io/32bitkid/post/understanding-delegated-javascript-events).

Comment: @TheAlpha thank you so much. I was able to fix it. I learned a new term: "event delegation".

Comment: Delegation shouldn't be needed if you're adding the listener after you've added the elements in the AJAX success function.

Comment: @Asperger, Glad you fixed it. You are most welcome :-)

Comment: Thank you @TheAlpha for the link, was stuck in a React project and the issue was resolved by event delegation.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be fixed with **event delegation**.

An example of how this works:

```
function gets() {
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.children[0])

  })
```

The **currentTarget** refers to the element we are actively clicking on and the **target** is the parent.

Comment: If he's adding the event listener after the AJAX has returned, he doesn't need to use delegation.

Comment: That's what I don't understand -- why doesn't it work? You only need delegation if you're trying to bind handlers for elements that don't exist yet.